# Jain SIP on android

Tags: android, sip, jain-sip

I need to implement SIP calls with JAIN-SIP api on Android. 
But can't find any working example. 
I want to download an example, set there my params (username, domain, password) and make a call.

Comment: (1/2) @AndrOvip, you can check https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/Examples/restcomm-helloworld sample application that underneath uses JAIN SIP. Keep in mind that the App doesn't directly use JAIN SIP. JAIN SIP is abstracted by a second higher level API, the Restcomm Android Client API. But still, the JAIN SIP client code is in a separate module which should help you in your enquiry. Please check https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/tree/master/restcomm.android.client.sdk/src/main/java/org/mobicents/restcomm/android/sipua. The heart of this module...

Comment: (2/2) ...is https://github.com/RestComm/restcomm-android-sdk/blob/master/restcomm.android.client.sdk/src/main/java/org/mobicents/restcomm/android/sipua/impl/SipManager.java